# In the application layer (using sequelize or other) abort SQL transaction if data already read (SELECT) has changed (UPDATE)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js

Is there a way with sequelize to detect if between my read (SELECT) query and my write (UPDATE) query, if another thread/process/transaction came in a changed the data that my SELECT query read.

A contrived example. Assume we have 2 functions. It seems unless I do the yearsRemaining calculation in SQL, I will always have a race condition.

```
function1() {
  let t1 = sequelize.transaction();
  let hobbitAge = sequelize.query(`SELECT age FROM hobbits WHERE name='Bilbo'`, { transaction: t1});
  let yearsRemaining = (131-hobbitAge);
  sequelize.query(`UPDATAE hobbits SET estimate=${yearsRemaining} WHERE name='Bilbo'`, { transaction: t1 });
  t1.commit();
}

function2() {
  let t2 = sequelize.transaction()
  sequelize.query(`UPDATAE hobbits SET age='111' WHERE name='Bilbo'`, { transaction: t2 });
  t2.commit();
}
```

The race condition is:

1. Transaction 1 runs first and reads a value of bilbo's age as 100 from the hobbits table
2. Transaction 2 starts running and updates the hobbits table (111), taking a write lock on the rows it's updating.
3. Transaction 1 waits until transaction 2 is finished writing to hobbits (same row). Once it has, as it is working off the old value read in the SELECT query (in the application layer), it puts a now incorrect value (81) into the hobbits table.

What is the best way of dealing with this in my application (javascript). Can I craft a query to deal with this in sequelize, or check the validity of my SELECT query before calling UPDATE? Or is the only way to work directly in the database (e.g. pure SQL query or a stored procedure).

Thanks

Comment: is the answer to go with a SELECT FOR UPDATE in SQL... which apparently in sequelize is a transaction with a lock (see https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html#static-get-LOCK)

Comment: "seems unless I do the yearsRemaining calculation in SQL". No SQL is the best place to do it. In fact i would go so far as to either NOT store it and just derive it in the select or define yearsremaining as a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html). (IMHO)

Comment: in this example that would make sense, but in more complicated scenarios (e.g. where a lot of variables/data that affect the query exist in my application layer) that wouldn't work out

Comment: That would be significant information in the original question? While simplified examples work you should not hide significant details, at least mention them. As far as not working out due to many variables, well I guess that is your opinion, mine is different. For years I have lived by the rule "if SQL can do that is where it should be done", especially if done at the table level. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called “optimistic locking”.

You can use [Sequelize's facilities](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/optimistic-locking.html) for that, which works with a version number that is checked for modifications on update.

The alternative is to use PostgreSQL's `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level. If such a transaction detects that a row has been modified by a concurrent transaction, it will throw a *serialization error*. This is probably the more efficient way to do it.

In both cases, you repeat the whole transaction if a concurrent modification is detected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see much documentation on optimistic locking (the link for more details goes nowhere helpful)?
From what I can gather, is the approach to wrap my database queries in a try/catch and if I catch an OptimisticLockError I would try all the queries from the start?

Comment: Yes, that's how optimistic locking works. Is that not what you want?